# WPF Sorting ItemsControl Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, xaml

I am currently trying to sort a `ItemsControl` by Name.  Currently I have the list printing out but can't seem to order it on the Views side.  I have the ability to order it on the Control or model side but want it to work from the view.

My `ItemsControl` has a binding to AllJobTypes (a list of class `JobTypes`).  `JobTypes` has a property called `Name` that I would like to sort in the view.

I have some debug code in the XAML that Prints out the count of each object.  The first 2 print out 'fail' and the last one works correctly.  What can i do to order `AllJobTypes` on the view side?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:JobTypeCreditUnionCountConverter x:Key="JobTypeCreditUnionCountConverter" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                        AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=AllJobTypes}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>

    <Label Foreground="SteelBlue" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">Job Types</Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding AllJobTypes.Count, FallbackValue='fail'}" />  //Fail
    <Label Content="{Binding cvs.Count, FallbackValue='fail'}" />  //Fail
    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                        AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=AllJobTypes}" /> //(Collection
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding cvs}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Comment: 3 hours ago you accepted an answer with `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"`. Why are you doing it differently now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" >
```